# Is there a lock rating system in the US?

Tags: security, us, lock

There are several questions already about what's the [best](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4904/what-is-the-best-bicycle-lock-on-the-market) [bike](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3164/whats-a-good-bike-lock-that-costs-less-than-30) [lock](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/141/best-bike-lock). I'm just looking for information on lock rating systems. I've found a couple rating systems in countries like UK ([Sold Secure](http://www.soldsecure.com/)) and the Netherlands (ART).

Is there a similar rating system in the US? Do they have a decent website that you can search on?

I've found that Sold Secure has a searchable site, but it does not have all of the US brands and models in its database.

Comment: The US military does, but not in general for the USA...http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WK63zd4uP4Y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple awnser to your question is **no**.

However their are a few other nations that have well established bike lock reviewer's, including "Thatcham and Sold Secure in the United Kingdom, ART in the Netherlands, SSF in Sweden, and VDS in Germany" [(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_lock)

With this in mind I'd suggest considering that individual bike lock brands will likely have their own security rating, which you should take into consideration depending on how much you value your bike.

Answer (score 2):

I know that some manufacturers, like [Kryptonite](http://www.kryptonitelock.com/TechLab/SecurityRatings.aspx) have systems that they assign their own locks, but I do not believe there is an independent rating agency in the United States.